# MariaDB pass aggregate function name as stored procedure parameter

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, mariadb, aggregate-functions

I'm writting stored procedure which gets **aggregate function name** and **column name** as parameters and returns value (example: ('sum','age') returns value of (SELECT SUM(age) FROM myTable))

my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sample (IN name VARCHAR(10), IN col VARCHAR(30), OUT result INT) 
BEGIN
    SELECT CONCAT( name , '(', col, ') ') INTO result FROM myTable;
END$
```

Comment: Google for "mysql prepared statements"...

Answer (score 0):

Make it a `FUNCTION` and

```
return CONCAT('SELECT ', name, '(', col, ') FROM myTable;');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Prepared Statements](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/prepare-statement/).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sample (IN name VARCHAR(10), IN col VARCHAR(30), OUT result INT) 
BEGIN
    SET @sql := '';
    SET @ret := 0;

    SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ', name,  '(', col, ') INTO @ret FROM myTable') INTO @sql FROM DUAL;
    PREPARE STMT from @sql;
    EXECUTE STMT;

    SELECT @ret INTO result FROM DUAL;

    DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;     
END
```